# Hosting web site on parse[dot]com

Tags: database, facebook-graph-api, hosting

I have started building an PHP website that uses Facebook's graph API and my question is: Can I host this website and the database on Parse.com?

Hosting the website on a "standard" hosting server is not an option, as I am dealing with a lot of data. I am having big troubles with the database latency and server configuration. The thing is that I need the web site hosted on something fast and budget accessible, and Parse.com might be exactly what I need, if I understood well the purpose of this [www.parse.com](http://www.parse.com).

Please excuse my noobish perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse.com forum answear: 
"
You can certainly store your data in Parse, using PHP to call our REST API. However, Parse Hosting does not offer an option for hosting PHP websites at this time, so you would need to find a different hosting provider."

---

What's Parse

It's a rather nice Backend-as-a-Service that'll store your JSON objects away for you. It also has a Cloud Code service which allows you to execute some server-side business logic right next to your data for efficiency and encapsulation.

Comment: You can host static/dynamic pages in parse.com. But there is a limitation: at most 500 files. So I think you can't use it for any serious dynamic website.